# systemctl enable fprintd.service fails

Tags: services, 19.10

Ubuntu 19.10

The fprintd.service file exists in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`.

`sudo systemctl start fprintd.service` works - starts the daemon

I want the `fprintd.service` to start on boot before login

`sudo systemctl enable fprintd.service` gives me

```
$ sudo systemctl enable fprintd.service
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units).
```

This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

How to fix???

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to follow the instruction of the message. Open the `fprintd.service` file in an editor and add the following line under the section `[Install]`

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This target is in most cases a good choice. If this doesn't work or you want another target, choose one by from this list

```
systemctl list-units --type target
```